# Is there a way to match the elements of an array to the keys of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am currently a student. This is one of the questions of an assignment:

An allergy test produces a single numeric score which contains the information about all the allergies the person has (that they were tested for). The list of items (and their value) that were tested are:

- eggs (1)
- peanuts (2)
- shellfish (4)
- strawberries (8)
- tomatoes (16)
- chocolate (32)
- pollen (64)
- cats (128)

So if Tom is allergic to peanuts and chocolate, he gets a score of 34.

Write a program that, given a person’s score can tell them:
a) whether or not they’re allergic to a given item
b) the full list of allergies.

Now the code I have is:

```
#A single numeric score is given, which is the sum of the combination of any item above 
#When there is only ONE item, the score can be: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 or 128
#when TWO items, the score can be: (1 + 2 =) 3, (1+ 4 =) 5, (1 + 8 =) 9, 17, 33 , 65 , 129..., 192
#When THREE items: 7, 11, 19, 35, 67, 131 ...., 224
#....
#When EIGHT items : 255
    
#Does order matter in this case? No. use combination

#Choose a do/while loop, given the numbers the user must be allergic to something no matter what


allergens = {
        "cats" => 1,
        "pollen" => 2,
        "chocolate" => 4,
        "tomatoes" => 8,
        "strawberries" => 16,
        "shellfish" => 32,
        "peanuts" => 64,
        "eggs" => 128,
    }

score = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
num_of_allergens = 1

puts "Please enter your given score: "
total_score = gets.chomp.to_i

loop do
    a1 = score.combination(num_of_allergens).to_a
    a2 = a1.map{|i| i.inject(:+)}
    if a2.include? total_score
        puts "You are allergic to: "
        a3 = a2.find_index(total_score)
        a4 = a1[a3]
        puts a4.map{|alrg| allergens.key(alrg)}
        break
    end
    if num_of_allergens > 255 || num_of_allergens < 1 
        puts "Please enter a valid number."
        break
    end
    num_of_allergens += 1
end
```

What I am trying to drive at is that I want to match a4 to the allergens hash so as to ultimately print out the key-value pair in the form of a hash to specify the allergens (num_of_allergens and total_score were fixed, now are inputs). Is this possible?

P.S. Given the particularity of the values of the hash(2^0, 2^1 .... ,2^7) , one of my fellow students came up with the idea of using this loop that looks like this:

```
if hash.each do |k,v|
  if score % value != score
    some_arr << (k,v)
    update score
  end
end
```

This should be the most direct and succint way to solve the problem, but still need a bit of time work something out. Could anyone please give me some pointers on that as well? Thank you!!

I edited the post, and I just managed to get the keys, but it is fine for now

Comment: Hint: `(1..allergens.size).each { |n| p allergens.values.first(n).sum }`. So, start subtracting from the score...

Comment: Does your instructor want you having other people do your assignment for you?

Comment: Do not vandalise your post please. Please read the [central FAQ on post deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). I've locked it again, to ensure you have time to understand the context of why we don't delete posts and what your options are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how the score of each allergene is a power of 2.
You can make use of this to calculate the offset to lookup the allergenes:

```rb
allergens = %w[eggs peanutes shellfish strawberries tomatoes chocolate pollen cats]

score = 34 # peanuts and chocolate
puts "Your score is: #{score}"
digits = score.digits(2)
digits.each_with_index do |digit, index|
  next if digit == 0

  puts "You are allergic to #{allergens[index]}"
end
```

So step by step:

`%w[]` is a shorthand to create an array of strings

The index of each allergene (starting at 0) within the array can be used to calculate its score:

`score_of_allergene = 2 ** index_of_allergene`

The score of the person can be converted to a binary representation, as array of digits:

`score.digits(2) # 2 => base 2 (binary) => [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

Now each the position of each `1` corresponds to a allergene the person reacted to, the `0` corresponds to an allergene the person did not react to.
So when we loop all flags, we can skip the `0`using `next if flag == 0`
and print all the other ones.

Comment: `digits` is nice for this: `34.digits(2)`  results in `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

Comment: oh, did not know `digits` thanks. Updated the answer to use `digits`, as recommended by @steenslag

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Comment: Check that [Intege#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-digits) returns already the reversed array of digits. So the Array#reverse here `score.digits(2).reverse` is cause of a wrong output. Just get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that:

```
(1..allergens.size).each { |n| p (allergens.values.sum - allergens.values.reverse.first(n).sum) }
# 127
# 63
# 31
# 15
# 7
# 3
# 1
# 0
```

And find that you can subtract values from the score in reverse order as soon as the result is positive:

```
total_score = 191

res = allergens.to_a.reverse.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), res|
    tmp = total_score - v
    if tmp >= 0
        total_score = tmp
        res << k
    end
end

res #=> ["eggs", "shellfish", "strawberries", "tomatoes", "chocolate", "pollen", "cats"]
```

---

Check the result:

```
res.sum { |k| allergens[k] }
#=> 191
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Lola has been found to be allergic to pollen and shellfish. Her allergy to pollen contributes `2` to her allergy score:

```
score = allergens["pollen"]
  #=> 2
```

Let's look at the bits that represent the integer `2`:

```
nbits = score.bit_length
  #=> 2
nbits.times.map { |i| score[i] }
  #=> [0, 1]
```

This means

```
0*(2**0) + 1*(2**1) #=> 2
```

See [Integer#bit_length](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-bit_length) and [Integer#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Now let's look at her shellfish score, forgetting about her pollen allergy.

```
score = allergens["shellfish"]
  #=> 32
nbits = score.bit_length
  #=> 6 
nbits.times.map { |i| score[i] }
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

We see that

```
0*(2**0) + 0*(2**1) + 0*(2**2) + 0*(2**3) + 0*(2**4) + 1*(2**5)
  #=> 32
```

Because each allergen has been assigned a score that is a power of `2` one bit of the score equals `1` and the remaining bits equals zero. Specifically, if the score equals `2**n`, it is the `n+1`th significant bit that will equal `1`.

Now let's compute Lola's total score:

```
score = allergens["pollen"] + allergens["shellfish"]
  #=> 34
```

```
nbits = score.bit_length
  #=> 6 
nbits.times.map { |i| score[i] }
  #=> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Notice that we could instead write

```
score = allergens["pollen"] | allergens["shellfish"]
  #=> 34
```

See [Integer#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-7C).

We first need to write a method that determines if, given a person's total score, they are allergic to a particular allergen.

As a first step, create a new hash, held by a constant, that maps each allergen to a power of two that corresponds to the bit that represents the allergen in the total score.

```
ALLERGEN_TO_BIT = allergens.transform_values do |n|
  n.bit_length-1
end
  #=> {"cats"=>0, "pollen"=>1, "chocolate"=>2, "tomatoes"=>3,
  #    "strawberries"=>4, "shellfish"=>5, "peanuts"=>6, "eggs"=>7}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

We may now write the method.

```
def allergic_to?(score, allergen)
  score[ALLERGEN_TO_BIT[allergen]] == 1
end
```

```
score = 34
allergic_to?(score, "pollen")
  #=> true
allergic_to?(score, "shellfish")
  #=> true
allergic_to?(score, "cats")
  #=> false
```

Now turn to the second task: given a total score return an array of the allergens to which the person is allergic.

```
def allergic_to(score)
  ALLERGEN_TO_BIT.keys.select do |allergen|
    score[ALLERGEN_TO_BIT[allergen]] == 1
  end
end
```

```
allergic_to(34)
  #=> ["pollen", "shellfish"] 
allergic_to(38)
  #=> ["pollen", "chocolate", "shellfish"] 
allergic_to(73)
  #=> ["cats", "tomatoes", "peanuts"]
```

Note that

```
ALLERGEN_TO_BIT.keys 
  #=> ["cats", "pollen", "chocolate", "tomatoes", "strawberries",
  #    "shellfish", "peanuts", "eggs"]
```

---

Suppose we were to compute

```
allergic_to(10_000)
  #=> ["strawberries"]
```

This is misleading, however, since `10000` is not a valid score. The minimum and maximum valid scores are seen to fall between `0` and `1+2+4+...+128`. Note that any integer between these limits is a valid score as it equals the sum of powers of two of some collection of distinct integers in this range.

`1+2+4+...+128` equals the sum of an geometric series, which equals <sup>1</sup> `2*(128)-1`.

We therefore could construct a method to check that a claimed score is indeed valid.

```
def valid_score?(score)
  score.between?(0, 2*(2**ALLERGEN_TO_BIT.values.max)-1)
end
```

```
valid_score?(-1)
  #=> false
valid_score?(0)
  #=> true
valid_score?(38)
  #=> true
valid_score?(255)
  #=> true
valid_score?(256)
  #=> false
```

<sup>1. I always forget the formula for a geometric series, but I remember how it is derived: `t = 1+2+4+...+128; 2*t = 2+4+...+128+2*(128); t = 2*t-t = 2*(128)-1`.</sup>